# Can there be something other than block verification that slows down synchronization in the end?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

In this question [When syncing Monero's blockchain from scratch, why does it begin fast and end slow?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/when-syncing-moneros-blockchain-from-scratch-why-does-it-begin-fast-and-end-sl/3721) the answers refer to validation and verification.

I've looked into Task Manager and for all Monero processes it keeps displaying 0% CPU usage, so it does not seem to be validating blocks.

Can there be other reasons? Something like bigger blocks, less seeders or daytime?

Since my data.mdb now is ~25GB and the blockchain.raw that I could have downloaded and imported instead is ~27GB, I wonder why the FAQ states that the fastest way to synchronize is from scratch using the wallet. It's missing just 2 GB and almost nothing happens.

Comment: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6651/my-gui-feels-buggy-freezes-all-the-time seems to help